# SQL Trying to concatenate 'ATTN" on a field when field is not NULL

Tags: t-sql, string-concatenation

I have been stuck with this for some time now and was hoping for a little help.

I am using SQL 2008 and creating a VIEW to use on a report, I am trying to do

```
SELECT
  SHIPNUMBER
 ,BILLADDRESS
 ,'ATTNCONTACT' = 'ATTN: ' + BILCONTACT
FROM PackingList
```

However I do not want the 'ATTN: ' to appear if BILCONTACT ISNULL, I would prefer it just stays null.

Any suggestions?

Comment: And in what way does what you have not do what you want?

Comment: Add `WHERE bilContact IS NOT NULL`?

Comment: @hvd, if BILCONTACT isnull then i still get the 'ATTN:' and I need it to stay as null or ''

Comment: @David, I still need the rest of the fields to show up even if BILCONTACT is null. Sorry if the ... adds confusion, I will edit my SELECT to show a little more information.

Comment: @jnoel10 No, you don't. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/14786

Comment: I'm confused then.  Can you give sample output that includes cases where `bilContact` is NULL and NOT NULL?

Comment: My apologies, they ended up not being null, I was expecting Null values but I guess since it is an optional field in the business logic it just makes it ''. Thank you all for the help

Comment: @jnoel10 Then for completeness, an alternative solution would be `'ATTN: ' + NULLIF(BILCONTACT, '')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the CASE but check for empty string too. The result is the same but you can write either way.

```
SELECT  'ATTNCONTACT' = CASE WHEN BILCONTACT IS NOT NULL AND BILCONTACT != '' THEN 'ATTN: ' + BILCONTACT END 
FROM PackingList

SELECT  CASE WHEN BILCONTACT IS NOT NULL AND BILCONTACT != '' THEN 'ATTN: ' + BILCONTACT END AS ATTNCONTACT
FROM PackingList
```

Comment: You could simplify the WHEN to `WHEN COALESCE(BILCONTACT,'') != ''`

Comment: Or even `WHEN BILCONTACT <> ''`, since a result of `UNKNOWN` and `FALSE` both cause the `CASE` to skip that part.